# Convert WideString to PWideChar

Tags: delphi, type-conversion, ocr, widestring

I use Nicomsoft OCR library to OCR images in Delphi. It is good for my tasks and it has Delphi unit-wrapper so it's easy to use it in Delphi. However, Delphi debugger shows "Range Error" message when I pass empty string as parameter value to some OCR functions. I checked the wrapper code and found that DLL library functions accept PWideChars as parameter but wrapper accepts WideString. Inside of unit-wrapper there is the following conversion:

```
function CallSomeOCRFunction(a: WideString);
var b: PWideChar;
begin
  b := @a[1];
  CallSomeDLLFunction(b); //passing "b" to DLL function that accepts PWideChar
  //.....
```

I did some research and discovered that many FAQs offer such conversion, for example: http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=PWideChar

It works if "a" is not empty string, but for empty string it cause "Range" error. How can I get pointer to first character of WideString variable correctly even if it is empty string? As far as I understand, even if string is empty it must contain zero character and PWideChar variable must point to it.

Comment: Pass it as `CallSomeDLLFunction(PWideChar(a));`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `PWideChar()` cast as described in the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/String_Types_(Delphi)#Mixing_Delphi_Strings_and_Null-Terminated_Strings). In your case it would be:

```
CallSomeDLLFunction(PWideChar(a));
```